# AWS Cognito sign up without password to get email confirmation link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, registration

I want to make a simple flow for registration app.
User sign up with only email -> The verification/registration link is sent to the email -> People register (putting in their password) on that link

I've googled anything but haven't found any way to make it with AWS Cognito.
Looks like Cognito is forcing users to sign up with at least email AND password to get the confirmation link

Comment: Are you sure you cannot call sign-up without a password? I don't see it as required here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#signUp-property

Answer (score 3):

You can sign up users with `adminCreateUser` API call. They will receive an email with temporary passwords. This approach is configurable.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html

Answer (score 1):

**Use: AdminCreateUser**

- Create a new user profile by using the AWS Management Console or by calling the AdminCreateUser API. Specify the temporary password(will be your user's password) or allow Amazon Cognito to automatically generate one.
- Specify whether provided email addresses and phone numbers are marked as verified for new users.
- Specify custom SMS and email invitation messages for new users via the AWS Management Console.
  Specify whether invitation messages are sent via SMS, email, or both.

**After successful user creation**,

```
 1. authenticate user using same user credentials
        Use: SDK calls InitiateAuth(Username, USER_SRP_AUTH)

 2. After success of initateAuth, amazon Cognito returns the PASSWORD_VERIFIER challenge with Salt & Secret block.

 3. Use RespondToAuthChallenge(Username, <SRP variables>, PASSWORD_VERIFIER

 4. Amazon Cognito returns the NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED challenge along with the current and required attributes.

 5. The user is prompted and enters a new password and any missing values for required attributes.

 6. Call RespondToAuthChallenge(Username, <New password>, <User attributes>).

 7. After successful password change user can be able to login using same credentials added by you.
```

**Short answer**

```
       -  In that case, you can specify the temporary password(will  allow Amazon Cognito to automatically generate one.).

       -  all user users will be forced to change their password only at first login.
```